# T SQL extend WHERE CLAUSE with case WHEN ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem in T SQL. I would like to extend my  statement with a `CASE WHEN` clause in the `WHERE` clause which depends on a local variable @counter2.

When the @counter2 has the value '2' ,the whole statement should be extended with the FETCH NEXT clause as you can see below to stop after 10 000 rows.

Currently I have the following statement for testing but it does not work like this. If the @counter2 variable has not the value '2'  the statement should be finished after the clause `where ID not in (1,2)`.

Is it possible to make it in that way?

```
DECLARE @counter2 INT = 0;

WHILE @counter2 <= 1
BEGIN
    SET @counter2 = @counter2 + 1

    SELECT *
    FROM companies
    WHERE ID NOT IN (1,2)
        AND CASE WHEN @counter2 = 2 THEN 
            ORDER ORDER ID
            OFFSET 0 ROWS
            FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY
    END

END
```

Comment: What are you thinking `FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY` will do here?

Comment: `where` and `order by` are separate clauses.  If you want to use the word `and` in the where clause, you add another filter, not an order by clause.

Comment: Either use `if` to pick between two possible select statements, or use manual paging based on `row_number()` instead of `fetch` (or the more appropriate `top`).

Comment: I think it would help if you just describe what you're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why?  Why return all the rows and then return 10000 sorted? Just return them all sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the case statement in your `FETCH NEXT` like so:

```
DECLARE @counter2 INT = 2

SELECT
    my_columns -- because we never use SELECT *
FROM
    Companies
WHERE
    id NOT IN (1, 2)
ORDER BY
    id
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT
    CASE
        WHEN @counter2 = 2 THEN 10000
        ELSE 999999999
    END ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but `IsNumeric()` returns 0 or 1.  It does not return 2.  Also, you cannot make the `order by` conditional.

Perhaps the condition you want is:

```
order by (case when @count2 = 2 then COPSYS_ID end)
```

Comment: OK. I have removed the IsNumeric() function, it is not necessary. 

Actually, I would like that the statement reads just 10 000 records if the @counter2 variable has the value '2'

And in T SQL you need with the 'FETCH NEXT 10 000 rows only' the 'order by' and 'OFFSET' clause because otherwise it doesn't work.